# Insert <li> element in a list's specific position respecting data-order attribute

Tags: jquery

I have a list with a numbered data-order attribute. This attribute isn't necessarily in a sequence like 1,2,3,4... but instead it's in a growing number sequence without a determined increase, something like 8,30,201,380.

What I want to do is insert an element in this list using jquery, respecting the order, so, if the data-order of the new element is 58, it would go between 30 and 201...

Since the elements are not in a set incremental sequence, a simple find and insert woudn't work, any ideas on how I can achieve this without wasting too much processing?

Comment: The obvious one would be iterate through every element, storing and testing previous value and next value, until find one that it belongs in the middle.. but I feel like there's a better way to do it.

Comment: iterating through every element is `O(n)`, which is good enough if your `n` is < 100, I wouldn't worry too much about processing speed here. But if your `n` is a large number, then there is option of storing each `<li>` in a `binary tree` which is `O(log n)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume ...

- `$ul` is the list node (jQuery-wrapped)
- `$li` is the list item to be inserted (jQuery-wrapped)

```
var o = $li.appendTo($ul).data('order');//initially, append $li to end of the list, and read its order attribute.
$ul.find("li").each(function() {
    if(o < $(this).data('order')) {
        $li.insertBefore(this); //if $li's order` is less than current item's order, then move $li above current item.
        return false; //break
    }
});
```

If, during the scan, the `o < $(this).data('order')` condition is not met, then the new list item will remain at the end of the list.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4ud127fm/)**

Answer (score 1):

When querying the DOM (*with jQuery methods*) you get back elements in the sequence they appear in the DOM.

So filtering your elements and then inserting after the last item with a value smaller than the new one..

```
  var newElementOrder = 10 // dummy value;

  var all = $('li[data-order]'),
      less = all.filter(function() {
          return +$(this).data('order') < newElementOrder;
      });

  if (less.length) {
    less.last().after(newElement);
  } else {
    all.first().before(newElement);
  }
```

**Full Demo**

```js
$('.add').on('click', function() {
  var newElementOrder = +$('.add-value').val(),
    newElement = $('<li data-order="' + newElementOrder + '">Item with order #' + newElementOrder + '</li>');

  var all = $('li[data-order]'),
    less = all.filter(function() {
      return +$(this).data('order') < newElementOrder;
    });

  if (less.length) {
    less.last().after(newElement);
  } else {
    all.first().before(newElement);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li data-order="8">Item with order #8</li>
  <li data-order="30">Item with order #30</li>
  <li data-order="201">Item with order #201</li>
  <li data-order="380">Item with order #380</li>
</ul>

<button class="add">add after</button>
<input type="text" class="add-value" />
```